# .delegate with the universal selector

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$('p').delegate('*', 'click', function () {
    console.log('You have clicked on the paragraph.');
});
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/pzP4Q/8/ for a working example.

The problem I am having is that, although I would have set `.delegate()` to catch all clicks on my paragraphs, it doesn't seem to catch clicks on text nodes.

How can I have `.delegate()` catch click events on text nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to delegate to paragraphs to listen for clicks on the text node. In most cases, the text comprises the element (in this case the 'p') anyhow. Usually delegating to a parent-level element to listen for clicks on the "p" is the more appropriate way to go.

Comment: I want to listen to all elements in the paragraph, not just the text nodes.

Comment: In which case, it's the "p" that you really want to listen for clicks on; anything inside that p will register as a click, though there are ways to have other clicks inside the p take precedence (an anchor tag should still be a working link I believe). See the revised delegation in my sample below. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case that it's really the 'p' that you want to listen for clicks on, it's just a matter of identifying an appropriate ancestor element. Usually this is a wrapper div, but it could be the body if need be:

```
$('#someElement').delegate('p', 'click', function() {
// your click function
})
```